# I can't build mlpack?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, mlpack

I am working on mlpack library (C++ machine learning library). I followed the steps of keon here: [building mlpack](http://keon.io/mlpack/mlpack-on-windows/#), but i got the following error in cmd ,when i reached the last step which is building mlpack:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24213.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24213.1
-- Check for working C compiler: F:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: F:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: F:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: F:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:51 (if):
Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
keywords when unquoted. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
details. Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
warning.

Quoted variables like "MSVC" will no longer be dereferenced when the policy
is set to NEW. Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be used.
This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:64 (if):
Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
keywords when unquoted. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
details. Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
warning.

Quoted variables like "MSVC" will no longer be dereferenced when the policy
is set to NEW. Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be used.
This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at CMake/FindArmadillo.cmake:326 (message):
ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND/armadillo_bits/config.hpp not found! Cannot
determine what to link against.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:189 (find_package)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have messed up your armadillo installation, to be more specific, you didn't specify the armadillo include dirs.

According to [this](http://qtandopencv.blogspot.kr/2015/09/deep-learning-04-compile-mlpack-1012-on.html) more detailed instruction, point 10:

> Specify the path of the libraries, dll and setup some definition, the details can found at [here](http://pastebin.com/hgBXvvhq)

So, you can try and add these lines to your mlpack's CMakeLists.txt:

`set(ARMADILLO_LIBRARY "C:/Users/yyyy/Qt/3rdLibs/armadillo/armadillo-5.600.2/vc2015_build/bin/vc2015_x86_amd64/release")
set(ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR "C:/Users/yyyy/Qt/3rdLibs/armadillo/armadillo-5.600.2/include")`

Comment: Hello Asalle, I don't have this "vc2015_build/bin/vc2015_x86_amd64/release"?

Comment: However, i added "set(ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR "C:\Users\Avrahim\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\armadillo-7.600.2\include")"  to cmakelist and still got the same error!

Comment: Hi there, it means, that you specified wrong paths, consider [this] (https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/511). You can do the following:
1. Make sure, AR..INCLUDE_DIR containes the config.hpp you need and all other armadillo headers.
2. Make sure, AR..._LIBRARY is the path to the dynamic lib, i. e. *.dll in your case
The guys from github (the link above) had a conversation about it and they kind of hacked it. If you get stuck with this, try installing armadillo any other way, if it's not possible, you can also ask the armadillo maintainers for help. Good luck!

Comment: This is my issue on github, you can check it: https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/856

Comment: I found in the cmakelists.txt the following: 

PATHS "C:/Program Files/Armadillo".

However, the path for Armadillo is:

C:\Users\Avrahim\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\armadillo-7.600.2

That is what you mean? Change the path of Armadillo inside cmakelists.txt?

Comment: Well, this ```PATHS``` is weird, you can try modifying it according to your actual armadillo installation. But I think, that somehow the variable ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR is empty. If you check the file Cmake/FindArmadillo.cmake, you can see, that at line 236 they throw an error if the enviromental var is not set. You can try setting it manually like [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310519/how-to-manage-environment-variables-in-windows-xp). It's for XP, but it's the same in newer Windowses.

Comment: Asalle, thanks a lot. Now after i built armadillo and mlpack. I tried out one of the examples, but nothing worked. I followed the following:
1: I first moved armadillo libraries to my new project folder, where i supposed to write my project. 
2: Then i added the libraires for armadillo from properties->c/c++->linker. 3: Next, i added the mlpack include folder to my project in order to include some of the methods. 
4: but still tell my some of the classes are not found!

Comment: Congratulations on your freshly built mlpack, @Avrahem :) Unfortunately, now that you've built mlpack your problem is out this question's scope. Consider creating a new question and including your example source code, desirable and present behaviour. Don't forget to specify the exact error message. Good luck!